# Is it safe to use $vars['name_raw'] instead of $vars['name']?

Tags: 7, users, security

I ran into an issue with usernames being trimmed in articles. I found a thread here with a fix suggesting to use $vars['name_raw']: https://www.drupal.org/node/854762#comment-7614255. It works.

But I'm wondering if $vars['name_raw'] should be sanitized with check_plain or not before being displayed to the screen. I'm not sure what the difference is between $vars['name'] and $vars['name_raw'] ? I searched and found no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular instance you should be fine because usernames already are filtered to a limited set of characters.

Like you assumed *_raw is unfiltered input. So in almost any other circumstance, it should be sanitized in some way before use.